# Can't see which line exceptions occurred on in script source files

Tags: unity, bug

After updating Unity to the new 2017.1.0f3 version, I can't see which line in a source file an exception occurred on.

Example: [image: Example]

I can't see the source of the error by double-clicking in the console either, which would usually redirect me to the source file in Visual Studio. I can still see exceptions from the Unity and Mono API.

I have managed to temporarily fix it by going to the PlayerSettings and switching "Scripting Runtime Version" from "Stable (.NET 3.5 Equivalent)" to "Experimental (.NET 4.6 Equivalent)".

This happens to all MonoBehaviour scripts.

Comment: What's the number at the right-hand side of that highlighted line? (514)

Comment: 514 lines long script? Looks very scary.

Comment: The number on the right shows how many time the same exception has occurred, and since itoccurs every frame, it shows a large number

Comment: This looks like a bug to report via Unity's issue tracker - It's not clear that fellow engine users will be able to solve this.